# Why are sins and hatred mentioned in Avinu Malkeinu?

Tags: tefilla

At the end of Chazaras HaShatz on Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur, we say a brief prayer that (in Nusach Ashkenaz) appears as follows:

> אבינו מלכנו זכר רחמיך וכבוש כעסך וכלה דבר וחרב ורעב ושבי ומשחית **ועון** ומגפה ופגע רע וכל מחלה וכל תקלה וכל קטטה וכל מיני פרעניות וכל גזרה רעה **ושנאת חנם** מעלינו ומעל כל בני בריתך
>
> Our Father, our King, remember Your compassion and suppress Your anger, bring an end to pestilence, bloodshed, famine, captivity, destruction, **iniquity**, plague, evil mishap, every illness, every obstacle, every strife, every sort of punishment, every evil decree, and **baseless hatred** from upon us and from upon all members of Your covenant.

The main theme of the passage seems to be that G-d should have mercy on us and withhold these terrible things from
us. Under that reading, the two boldfaced terms seem out of place: sins are dependent on the sinner (“everything is in the hands of Heaven except for fear of Heaven” - Berachos 33b), and baseless hatred is dependent on the hater (one of *his* sins). So how can we say that HaShem should withhold these from us when it’s not up to Him?

<sup>I know some of you are pointing to “everything is in the hands of Heaven except for [diseases caused by] cold [and] hot” - Kesuvos 30a - which seems to indicate that I should ask on pestilence, plague, and sickness, but that Gemara is seemingly a narrow case; most diseases are, in fact, caused by things besides temperature, as that very Gemara proceeds to discuss. However, this question *can* be asked on the similar line in the standard Avinu Malkeinu prayer, כלה דבר וחרב ורעב ושבי ומשחית **ועון** ושמש מבני בריתך, but for the same reason cannot be asked on the following line, מנע מגפה מנחלתיך.</sup>

Comment: I believe some rites say a variant of this for all 10 days in that spot

Comment: עון=ע-ו-ה "המעוות אינו יכול לתקון?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I don’t follow. How are you attempting to translate the word?

Comment: More "twisted" than actual iniquity. I.e. help preserve us from the twisted thinking that LEADS to sin.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Interesting. Not usually how the word is translated (and I can’t think of a place where the word עון means anything but sin/iniquity/other fancy synonym, even while other words from the same root mean something else).

Comment: @DonielF though not a perfect fit, many use this interpretation of העוינו vs עוינו; twisting others vs oneself.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky העוינו is just the causative form of עוינו. However you translate עוינו, then העוינו is just doing that to others.

Comment: ... exactly my point?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Just making sure I understood you correctly. :)